# How can I set the "git tag" message as an environment variable in Github Actions?

Tags: bash, github, github-actions, github-release

I want to automate the release process of pypdf. The idea is that I just push a git tag and a Github Action creates a Github release.

In Bash, I use the following to set the `tag_body:

```bash
latest_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
tag_body=$(git tag -l "${latest_tag}" --format='%(contents:body)')
```

That works. But I also get the desired name with the following two steps, but the `tag_body` variable is always empty:

```
      - name: Prepare variables
        id: prepare_variables
        run: |
          git fetch --tags --force
          latest_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
          echo "latest_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          echo "tag_body<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "$(git tag -l \"${latest_tag}\" --format='%(contents:body)')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          echo "tag_body2=$(git tag -l \"${latest_tag}\" --format='%(contents:body)')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "tag_body3=$(git tag -l ${git describe --tags --abbrev=0} --format='%(contents:body)')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Create GitHub Release 
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Version ${{ env.latest_tag }}, ${{ env.date }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
          body: Body is ${{ env.tag_body }}
```

My suspicion is that it's either due to escaping or due to the multi-line string. How can I make the `tag_body` variable have the same value as locally in Bash?

### Context

In case you wonder about the project: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/pull/1970

Comment: Use `fetch-depth: 0` with `actions/checkout@v3` to fetch the git history.

Comment: I have that in a previous step. I get the tag name, so the cloning is not the issue

Comment: Got it. You are manually fetching the tags before the `latest_tag` is set [here](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/actions/runs/5569764049/workflow#L42-L49). Looks like the workflow is working fine now, right? I see that the PR has been merged.

Comment: No, it's not. I merged it because I can manually edit the release and set the body. So it's already helpful, but not working completely as desired

Comment: Right. Tested your [scenario](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJyFUc1PwjAUv/eveFkwg8PExFvDiNEgetGDH9el695YBdpl7SAL8r/bMrY5RL20fX2/j/ch2RopLISJDFtEXEmD0ugoVklFiJIUtqpYpiu1jRKhc2Z4RsiHijUlAFy4E6AopQ4ctoxLacpgxQxqQw45bTDXNSwAeTC7y5AvVWkOnwClRk2BcSOU1GN+TN5sro/5rTAZPb6tF+ZKC6OKikJeBXmSjvPKnqRn8YKNuq2NwmdLt41CirYLCALbsLZXqgqOLaCu3Q0jHAwdOkHNCxFjR2BxXOAmvBq1JOSZAq+jUhh0gdeDtYEbt5ty6NU+NoZgBd53Zl3dmpnQvxg2u6GONfJH3ol9I2jNm+cv1n38ZDJ7vvdgOrXe88fXh7fbaPb0fqreaf6HPK/WW8+8XQ/KDf0xEgr+YLdzucvmC/Z7//xG/2j+Cynk0Ck=). See: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5573292945/jobs/10180372007

Comment: Have you tried to put all commands of `run` in a script ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag_body` is blank in your example because the following outputs blank:

```
echo "$(git tag -l \"${latest_tag}\" --format='%(contents:body)')"
```

You can verify that this is blank locally by doing:

```
echo "$(git tag -l \"3.12.2\" --format='%(contents:body)')"
```

By removing the `\"` around the `$latest_tag` reference, you will see that echo then output something:

```
echo "$(git tag -l ${latest_tag} --format='%(contents:body)')"
```

at which point the pipe into `$GITHUB_ENV` will now receive data. However, you could drop the `echo` altogether and pipe the output of the command itself into `$GITHUB_ENV` instead of passing it to echo to pipe it:

```
git tag -l "${latest_tag}" --format='%(contents:body)')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```